# JPA Transformer for JPQL Query Result

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In JPA 2.1 I need to transform the result of a JPQL Query to a custom POJO object.

I'm aware of the following solution but I **can't** use it because I don't have a native SQL query.

```
@Entity
@Table("USER_T")
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="SearchResult", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = InternalUser.class, 
        columns = {@ColumnResult(name="userId"), @ColumnResult(name="firstName"),
                @ColumnResult(name="lastName"), @ColumnResult(name="role")
        })
    })
```

Then in my DAO class,

```
javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(jpql, "SearchResult");
```

If I were to try this approach I would get SQL Exceptions because the `jpql` variable isn't native SQL. It holds a JPQL expression, which allows some "extras" like specifying a custom field in a Where clause or an Order-By.

So instead of `createNativeQuery(strQuery, strMapping)` I need `createQuery(strQuery, strMapping)` -- but that one doesn't exist. Any suggestions? I still need to transform the result to a custom POJO.

Comment: `select new SearchResult(...) from ...`.

Comment: Thanks, the syntax was the ClassName for the result with 'select new (..)'

Answer (score 0):

Per JB Nizet's tip, the JPQL auto-transformation syntax is

```
private static final String SEARCH_JPQL = "select new  mydomain.InternalUser( " +
                       " users.id as userId,  " +
                       " abc.preferredFirstname as firstName,  " +
                       " abc.preferredLastname as lastName, " +
                       " users.role as role ) " +
    " from ... "
```

The class name in the Select is the POJO to receive the result set. 
But there had to be a constructor to support that. So I added

```
public InternalUser(String userId, String firstName, String lastName, String role) {
   this.userId = userId;
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;
   this.role = role;
}
```